# how to change the number of displayed products in Prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have developed an online PrestaShop store !
everything is OK, but i dont know how to change the number of products to be displayed in home tabs

Thankyou in advance-

i use PrstaShop 1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it in `Modules` -> `Modules` -> `Featured products on the homepage` -> `Number of products to be displayed`

Answer (score 0):

You can change it in Modules -> Modules -> New products block -> Products to display

Comment: What version is this for?